# How do I set a private static array in C++ via a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, static

I have a class which contains, as a member, a large array.

```
exampleclass{
public:
   ...
   static void set_array();
   static int somearray[1000];
};
```

(The array should be private, but for quick and dirty testing purposes I set it to public. See below)

Now, the array is initialized with:

```
int exampleclass::somearray[1000];
```

Which means all my values are 0. So far, all is fine

Now, I wish to initialize this with a function, which is defined as follows:

```
void exampleclass::set_array()
{
memset(somearray, 0, sizeof(somearray));
FILE* fin= fopen("myfile.dat", "rb");
size_t bytesread= fread(somearray, sizeof(somearray), 1, fin);
fclose(fin);
}
```

All this is included in a headerfile

If I use this outside of any class (i.e.: somearray[1000] is a global variable, and I call the above function as a global one from the main function, everything works like a charm.

But when I now do the following from the main function:

```
int main()
{
  exampleclass::set_array();
  for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
  {
      std::cout << exampleclass::somearray[i] << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
0
0
0
...
0
```

Even though I am expecting it to output the values it read from the myfile.dat.

What am I doing wrong? How can I tell the class to modify the static member with the function I provided?

Comment: Did you try debugging it? There are a ton of things that could be going on...

Comment: 1) "All this is included in a headerfile" Definition of `int exampleclass::somearray[1000];` shouldn't be in a header. 2) Did you check, that after `FILE* fin= fopen("myfile.dat", "rb");` `fin` is not NULL ? 3) Does file "myfile.dat" contains non-zeros ?

Comment: Hi borisbn
1) Alright, changed that, but it didn't solve the problem. (why is this bad, by the way?)
2) It shouldn't be, since, as mentioned, it works if this is done outside of a class structure.
3) Yes, it ONLY contains non-zero values

Comment: 1) it *will* be bad, if you'll include this header from more then one sources. In this situation you will have multiple definitions of `exampleclass::somearray[1000]` 2) ok 3) ok 4) use tenfour's advice

Comment: @Mark Have you checked what the value of `bytesread` is before you `fclose`?

Comment: BTW, fread returns "The total number of elements successfully read is returned", but not bytes count. As if you ask `1` element it will return `1` or `0` if fail

Comment: Psychic long-shot guess: You didn't use the same names for the global array and the static class member. When you added the class member you kept the old variable around and you're still referencing that in `set_array`.

Comment: Have you considered using `std::array` instead of a C-style array?

Comment: Hi, molbdnilo. No, sorry, that wasn't it, either. I rechecked the entire code. There's no other variable of that name, and no global variables either.

Comment: did you check the bytesread returned ?

Answer (score 0):

using operator sizeof() on an array doesn't always behave the way you might expect. Depending on the context, the array can be interpreted as just a pointer, as described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/arrays/sizeof-array/#basics).

I think what you actually want to do is change to [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/?kw=fread) to:

```
size_t numread = fread(somearray, sizeof(int), 1000, fin);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sizeof() on an array doesn't always behave the way you might expect"

Comment: I understood your point, but I was thinking more that you edit your answer so that people might understand what you mean without looking in the comments.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I'm a little new here and didn't understand the inference. I added the link.

Comment: Just tried it, that wasn't it, unfortunately. Even tried setting all values manually, it still gives the same result. It's as if that function is never even called.

Comment: @Mark: Then mostly like the function *was* never called. You haven't posted enough code to tell what is happening. What do you think you've done to call that initialization function?

Comment: The function IS called. This is why I said "it's as if". I checked, since a std::cout within the function outputs something correctly. So the function is called, the array simply remains unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fread reads from the stream as a character (My guess) , so try changing the somearray in to **static char somearray[1000]** , i think it will work

***Note :** The fread even reads "\0" as a single character*